# React: How to use react table with a checkbox so that if it is checked the complete row is selected and pushed/assigned to input fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table, react-table

I want to make a table (fig2) with the following scenario.

1. An API is there with key/value pair data
2. Whenever one row/key is checked then the entire row will be checked and their name will be pushed/assigned to the input fields
3. And if the checkbox is unchecked then the data will be removed
4. Also, there is one check All checkbox which will select all the checkbox.
5. Above points 2,3,4 are applicable for each single checkboxes

Is it possible to make this table by using the react-table package?
How this table can be made in react js by using a react-table package or simple HTML table.

[Fig1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meldU.png) : Shows the API Response   
[Fig2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnGTe.png) : Shows the table to be built

```
handleGetPermissionGroup(event) {
const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
axios({
  method: "GET",
  url: "http://192.168.0.24:8004/api/getPermissionGroup",
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
  },
}).then((res) => {
  const arrKeys = Object.keys(res.data);
  const arrValues = Object.values(res.data);
  this.setState({ arrayOfKeys: arrKeys });
  this.setState({ arrayOfValues: arrValues });
  console.log("getPermissionGroup:", res.data);
  console.log("Values:", Object.values(res.data));
  console.log("Keys:", Object.keys(res.data));
});
}
<table class="table ">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Modules</th>
                        <th scope="col">Permissions</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {this.state.arrayOfKeys.map((item, i) => (
                        <tr>
                          <td scope="row">
                            {item}
                            <input
                              className="m-l-4"
                              type="checkbox"
                              name=""
                              id=""
                              value=""
                            />
                          </td>

                          <td>
                            {this.state.arrayOfValues.map((items, i) => (
                              <td>
                                <input
                                  className="m-r-4"
                                  type="checkbox"
                                  name=""
                                  id=""
                                  value=""
                                />
                                {items.name}
                              </td>
                            ))}
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      ))}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
```

In Fig3 I have this response, the issue in this is that I can not access the name/group_name of values

[Fig3 (My Work)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIGAI.png)

Comment: What have you tried ? Can you chare your code...

Comment: I have edited my question. you can see the block of my code